# Cut one string into two others in Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, nsstring, nsurl

I have an NSURLRequest being made that to a server that returns a string.

```
string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`receivedData` is the mutable array that the downloaded data is stored in. Everything works fine.

I have now, however, added another value to that string. An example of the returned string would be `14587728000000 , 376.99`. Originally it was one value so I didn't have to do any splicing. **But**, now that I have another value, I want to be able to separate it into two different strings.

What should I do to separate the two values into different string? Some kind of search that goes till the first space, or something like that. I have access to the server, and the string is generated in PHP so the separator can be anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `NSString` [`componentsSeparatedByString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method:

```
NSString *string = @"14587728000000,376.99";
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
```

You can find some other common `NSString` tricks (where I found this one) [here](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString).

Comment: So this will add the strings to `chunks[0]` and `chunks [1]`?

Comment: Keep in mind you'd be accessing [chunks objectAtIndex:0] and not chunks[0]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`-(NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) and pass in the token to split by.